# Getting conversion error on unused value when using context.SaveChages()

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Working on a semester-long project from a code-based that was inherited from last semester's students. Trying to add a simple method that updates a boolean field `isPaid` on an `application` class. When I call `context.SaveChanges()` I get the error:

```
SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2ab5dcc9-f6f8-464c-aa35-1832d6ed8018' to data type int.
```

In the code below I am passing in the ApplicationId updating the IsPaid variable. However, I'm receiving an error on the StudentId. The `context.SaveChanges()` method is called in other parts of the program with no such error. Could not be more confused any help would be much appreciated
Here is a picture of the debug window https://ibb.co/6WZGmMX

```
        public void Paid(int id)
        {
            Application app = DbContext.Application.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ApplicationId == id);
            app.IsPaid = true;
            DbContext.Application.Update(app);
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Error message I am receiving:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2ab5dcc9-f6f8-464c-aa35-1832d6ed8018' to data type int.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action<Action> wrapCloseInAction)
```

```
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
```

Comment: seems like Application has a guid instead a int as ID

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing your `Paid` method parameter to a GUID instead of integer ID?

```
public void Paid(Guid id)
```

Based on your error message, the method is passing in a Guid as an int, so that's why the error is being thrown.

If this does not work, try checking the contents of `app.Id` to see what that value is.

The issue is not with `context.SaveChanges()` itself, it is an issue with the specific data being saved in this particular method.

Comment: The value I'm passing in is the Application Id which is an int. The error message is happening on the StudentId which I agree should be a guid but was saved as a string. Here is a pic of the debug console https://ibb.co/6WZGmMX